# Why does exporting withAlert(Alerts) causes error but withAlert()(Alerts) works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [Brad's tutorial](https://youtu.be/Fia-GGgHpK0?t=344) the `Alerts` component is exported using:

```
export default withAlert(Alerts)
```

This was causes the errors:

```
The above error occurred in one of your React components:
    in Unknown (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://fb me/react-error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:21810:13
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Unknown (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App 2 main.js line 753 > eval:14729:15
```

After reading [react-alerts documentation](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert) the export was changed to the below and it works:

```
export default withAlert()(Alerts)
```

In essence:

- Was this change correct?
- What did that change do?
- Why was it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes. It's correct.
- Since the api of react-alerts change, you should update the code. The changing information is described in this link https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert/commit/9decd399fccc42c623bfdd44cd6fc381d75c3116
- to follow the published api, since you used their code :). I guess they added some arguments inside the bracket to customize the alert. But the important is the guide in youtube used the older version than current.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: `withAlert()` returns a function which is similar to the previous `withAlert` function?

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same.